# How to parse numeric element in xml using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I need help in parsing xml in Powershell (I am new).

Here is the code that has a bug. The second Write-Output does not print the expected output of 31.50.

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content "input.xml"
$node = $XmlDocument.Transaction
Write-Output "$($node.TranDate)"
Write-Output "$($node.Amount)"
```

input.xml has the following lines:

```
<Transaction id="7648">
  <TranDate>2018-09-13</TranDate>
  <Amount currency="840">31.50</Amount>
</Transaction>
```

I get the following output:

```
2018-09-13
System.Xml.XmlElement
```

As you can see, TranDate field prints fine but Amount element does not. How do I parse the numeric value? I wish 31.50 to be printed for the second Write-Output statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the contents of the element itself with `$node.Amount.'#text'` or `$node.Amount.InnerText`.

If you want to parse the value as a decimal number, do:

```
[decimal]::Parse($node.Amount.InnerText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two child nodes (attribute and text), you must explicitly select `InnerText`:

```
$xml = [xml]'<Transaction id="7648">
  <TranDate>2018-09-13</TranDate>
  <Amount currency="840">31.50</Amount>
</Transaction>'

Write-Output $xml.Transaction.Amount.InnerText
```